# What are the type of settings you would expect to see in a taxi-sharing application?

Tags: mobile-application

I'm working on a mobile app which allows users to book and share taxi journeys. The app has the following features:

- Each user on the app has a profile with a timeline of all their recent journeys (similar to Twitter)
- Users can follow one another to keep track of each others journeys and jump into any journey they spot on the timeline (all of these journeys are summarised on the home screen - once again similar to Twitter)
- Users can message one another (only if they are following each other)
- Users can request seats in each others taxis

What sort of settings (configurable) would you expect to see in such an app (e.g. account/profile/content settings). I have a few ideas:

- Option to deactivate/delete your account
- Protect my journeys - future journeys will not be available publicly
- Add location to journeys - app will store locations that all jobs are made from
- Reset password
- Email notifications - when a direct message is sent, when user is followed by someone new, when a user requests to share a journey
- Edit profile/header image, name, location and bio
- Edit account settings - email address, language

Do you think the above is appropriate? 
What more could I add?

Comment: What else do you *need*?

Comment: This  is not a UX question. You are using this forum as your market/requirements research. You better go out and ask that to your target audience.

Comment: Apologies if overly blunt, but I think you may well be asking the wrong question.  Most users want to see the least UI needed to get the job done. UX activity should be to isolate key goals, support those well, and don't do non-essentials. i.e. More features does **not** imply better.  Hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an Android phone user, I would expect:

- An estimate of how much of a taxi might cost me, and perhaps a quick way to split the cab fare (including tip).
- A way to look for alternate ways to get home (like public transit, or walking, without having to re-enter the destination), since where I usually need a taxi, it's almost impossible to get a taxi during certain times of day.
- A way to start my car navigation app (not needing to re-enter the destination), in case the taxi doesn't know where it's going, or I just want to double check the route he's taking.
- An in-phone status bar notification, not necessarily an email notification.
- A quick way to turn off notifications, or better yet, the app would be smart enough to stop notifying me when it knows I'm in the taxi and well underway.
- Some good haptic/vibration/sound settings for notifications to compensate for street noise when waiting for a taxi, or for the noise inside a crowded bar.
- And finally, I'd want to make sure the developer was really frugal with my battery usage. I realize that gps polling, data connection, etc. takes a lot of energy, and if the level of my battery falls below a certain level, I'd want it to not use as much functionality as possible.